# Determine the probability of the independent event.

Tags: statistics

Jade has two sets of three cards face down on a table. Each set contains the 2 of hearts, the 5 of diamonds, and the 8 of clubs. He randomly turns over one card from each set.

Determine the probability of the sum of the numbers is greater than 8.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My answer is 6/9 but I used a probability tree to solve that. how about other method?

Comment: It's better to edit your question to show your work rather than adding a comment.  That way people are more likely to see your work, and less likely to vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3} x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^5 + \frac{1}{3} x^8$$
The relation of $f(x)$ to the problem is that the coefficient of $x^n$ is the probability of selecting a card of rank $n$ from a single set.  When expanded, $f(x)^2$ is
$$f(x)^2 = \frac{1}{9}x^4 + \frac{2}{9}x^7 + \frac{3}{9}x^{10} + \frac{2}{9}x^{13} + \frac{1}{9}x^{16} $$
The coefficient of $x^n$ in $f(x)^2$ is the probability that two cards drawn, one from each set, sum to $n$.  So the probability the sum is greater than $8$ is the sum of the coefficients of $x^7$, $x^{10}$, $x^{13}$ and $x^{16}$:
$$\frac{3}{9} + \frac{2}{9} + \frac{1}{9} = \boxed{\frac{2}{3}}$$
To see how this works, it helps to think of $f(x)^2$ as
$$\left(\frac{1}{3} x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^5 + \frac{1}{3} x^8\right) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{3} x^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^5 + \frac{1}{3} x^8 \right)$$
and then expand by taking one term from the left factor $f(x)$ and one term from the right factor $f(x)$ in all possible ways, so there are $3 \times 3 = 9$ combinations in all.  If you carry out this computation, I think you will see that you have reproduced the computation in your probability tree.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3*3*3= 27 such combinations:
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 5)
(2, 2, 8)
(2, 5, 2)
(2, 5, 5)
(2, 5, 8)
(2, 8, 2)
(2, 8, 5)
(2, 8, 8)
(5, 2, 2)
(5, 2, 5)
(5, 2, 8)
(5, 5, 2)
(5, 5, 5)
(5, 5, 8)
(5, 8, 2)
(5, 8, 5)
(5, 8, 8)
(8, 2, 2)
(8, 2, 5)
(8, 2, 8)
(8, 5, 2)
(8, 5, 5)
(8, 5, 8)
(8, 8, 2)
(8, 8, 5)
(8, 8, 8)

The only one where the sum is NOT greater than 8 is the first (2, 2, 2) where the sum IS 8.  The probability the sum is greater than 8 is 26/27, NOT 6/9.